# Understanding the function definition of the tensor product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook states

> Formally, the tensor product of matrices is a function

> $\otimes: \mathbb{C}^{m\times m'} \times \mathbb{C}^{n\times n'} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{mn\times m'n'}$

> and it is defined as

> $(A\otimes B)[j, k] = A[j/n, k/m] \times B[j \text{ Mod } n, k \text{ Mod } m].$

The $A[j/n, k/m]$ is hard for me to understand. My reading of it is that this quantity is the $j/n$th row and $k/m$ column of the matrix A. But for most values of $j, n, k,$ and $m$, $j/n$ and $k/m$ will be fractions, and I don't see how fractional row and column indices make any sense.

In contrast, $B[j \text{ Mod } n, k \text{ Mod } m]$ makes sense to me because $j \text{ Mod } n$ and $k \text{ Mod } m$ will return whole number values.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think they mean $\lfloor j/n\rfloor$.

Comment: It might make more sense if you look up “Kronecker product” and see the block matrix definition

Comment: I like the modulus definition. $A\otimes B$ is tiled by A (that is, it consists of a bunch of adjacent copies of A, just with different elements of $B$ associated). Surely, given a location, modulus would say which element corresponds in $A$. For the element of $B$, we use the other piece of information that modulus throws away (the multiple). Like in $a=q*b+r$, the $q$.